# Filtrar por fin de semana en un rango determinado de horas. Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, datetime, orm

me encuentro intentando realizar una consulta que me regrese el numero de ordenes que su fecha de entrega sea durante el fin de semana comprendido entre las 7 am - 11 am y lo he estado intentado de la siguiente forma:

```
Order.objects.filter(delivery__range=[breakfast_start_date, datetime.now()],
state__in=order_states, delivery__week_day__gte=6,
delivery__time__between=( datetime.time(datetime.strptime('07:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')),
datetime.time(datetime.strptime('11:00:00', '%H:%M:%S'))))
```

pero me da el siguiente error:

```
FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'between' for TimeField or join on the field not permitted.
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda para resolver esto.

Y en mi modelo el campo esta declarado de la siguiente forma:

```
delivery = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

Estoy utilizando la versión 1.11.5 de Django

Comment: Hola, ¿el campo `delivery` es un `DateTimeField`? Tal vez también puedes mostrar tus modelos

Comment: Edite la pregunta y agregue lo que me preguntas @César

Comment: Efren, ¿qué versión de Django estás usando?

Comment: La versión 1.11.5 @César

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues aunque en la documentación señala que se debe utilizar `__between`

yo lo hice con `__range` y me funcionó de la siguiente manera:

```
delivery__time__range=(time(7, 0, 0), time(11, 0, 0))
```

De esta forma Pude solucionar mi problema.